# slidetoggle and toggleclass problems

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slidetoggle, toggleclass

I have problem on this website. www.runebs.dk (I know its a bit weird but I have a password at the moment just so everyone can't see the site, anyways the code is Rune)

I have two problems:

The first problem is that I have this `toggleClass()` which works perfect on the following code but I want the same effect to the logo and the text under so when you hit information on the site the logo and text turn into white like information does.

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass( "white" );
});
```

I have tried with this code but I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $('#logo').toggleClass( "white" );
});
```

The other problem is that I use a plugin in Wordpress called **collapse-o-matic** which works as a `slidetoggle`. The problem here is that all the content on the page moves when you hit the [x]. I don't want that.. I should only be the info the "goes up and down"

Can someone help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have two anchor `<a href="">whatever</a>` tags nested inside your logo that have color property set to black `color: black;`

Try making your jQuery selector more specific and adding the class to the anchors instead of the `#logo` id.

Something like this:

```
$('#about').click(function() {
    $('#logo a').toggleClass("white");
});
```

I've been unable to duplicate your slideToggle problem. Everything stays put for me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. Do you think it better to make the slidetoggle in jquery instead of using a plugin?

Comment: A simple slideToggle like what you are doing is only a few lines of jQuery. It would probably be very easy to do and it would mean one less plugin that you have to load.